# Offset top of fixed element is 0 on android 4.2.1

Tags: javascript, android, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I'm using Bootstrap Affix to fix an element to the top of the window when it's scrolled past.

However in the android stock browser will calculate `el.offset().top` relative to the window instead of the body. Which causes the Affix pluggin to change the class to `affix-top` instead of `affix`.

Is there another way to calculate the elements position relative to the body?

The css I use is a simple:

```
.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```